# Is Anki (for Windows) open-source and safe?

Tags: malware, spyware, open-source, source-code, anki

Is [Anki’s](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) (for Windows) source code available? On this page, the Windows tab doesn't show a source download. But its Linux tab does. Is Anki for Windows safe, i.e. malware/spyware free?

Comment: How does open source relate to malware-free?  Unless the app is trivial, how could you tell from looking at a mountain of code whether it contains any malware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the Source header in the [Development] tab at https://apps.ankiweb.net/, it says that "stable releases are available on the Linux/BSD tab", so the source under the Linux/BSD tab is also the source for the compiled Windows and Mac versions of the software.

Development versions of the source are also available at https://github.com/dae/anki. You can inspect the code yourself to verify whether it is safe to use.

Comment: +1. I don’t know much about Linux or GitHub. Bear w/ me. The tab lists a .deb & .tgz file. I thought .deb is the Linux-equivalent of .exe? If Linux can install from .deb & if it also contains source code, does that mean Linux compiles it & then installs? If there’s no compile-time OS detection, wouldn’t this still be Linux-specific? I know less about .tgz & am wondering if that’s similar. For GitHub, where’s the source? Is it in 1 archive file? Just want to know if Win. source is really there, hoping that if they really open-sourced Win. version & no one complained yet, that installer's safe?

Comment: No, Windows would be .exe but if your worried compile from source